# SQL SERVER How to UPDATE all rows in a table that exists in other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, division, exists

I have the this UPDATE SENTENCE that update rows if exists doing a division for every row, every row has a different Rate/HR

```
UPDATE CP_ValueStream_Data
        SET
        CP_ValueStream_Data.W1 = (SELECT ROUND(CAST((SELECT [CP_Demand_G&PS].W1 FROM [CP_Demand_G&PS]) AS FLOAT)/CAST(Rate AS FLOAT),2)),
        CP_ValueStream_Data.W2 = (SELECT ROUND(CAST((SELECT [CP_Demand_G&PS].W2 FROM [CP_Demand_G&PS]) AS FLOAT)/CAST(Rate_Hr AS FLOAT),2)),
        CP_ValueStream_Data.W3 = (SELECT ROUND(CAST((SELECT [CP_Demand_G&PS].W3 FROM [CP_Demand_G&PS]) AS FLOAT)/CAST(Rate_Hr AS FLOAT),2)),
        CP_ValueStream_Data.W4 = (SELECT ROUND(CAST((SELECT [CP_Demand_G&PS].W4 FROM [CP_Demand_G&PS]) AS FLOAT)/CAST(Rate_Hr AS FLOAT),2)),
        CP_ValueStream_Data.W5 = (SELECT ROUND(CAST((SELECT [CP_Demand_G&PS].W5 FROM [CP_Demand_G&PS]) AS FLOAT)/CAST(Rate_Hr AS FLOAT),2)),
        CP_ValueStream_Data.W6 = (SELECT ROUND(CAST((SELECT [CP_Demand_G&PS].W6 FROM [CP_Demand_G&PS]) AS FLOAT)/CAST(Rate_Hr AS FLOAT),2)),
        CP_ValueStream_Data.W7 = (SELECT ROUND(CAST((SELECT [CP_Demand_G&PS].W7 FROM [CP_Demand_G&PS]) AS FLOAT)/CAST(Rate_Hr AS FLOAT),2)),
        CP_ValueStream_Data.W8 = (SELECT ROUND(CAST((SELECT [CP_Demand_G&PS].W8 FROM [CP_Demand_G&PS]) AS FLOAT)/CAST(Rate_Hr AS FLOAT),2)),
        CP_ValueStream_Data.W9 = (SELECT ROUND(CAST((SELECT [CP_Demand_G&PS].W9 FROM [CP_Demand_G&PS]) AS FLOAT)/CAST(Rate_Hr AS FLOAT),2)),
        CP_ValueStream_Data.W10 = (SELECT ROUND(CAST((SELECT [CP_Demand_G&PS].W10 FROM [CP_Demand_G&PS]) AS FLOAT)/CAST(Rate_Hr AS FLOAT),2)),
        CP_ValueStream_Data.W11 = (SELECT ROUND(CAST((SELECT [CP_Demand_G&PS].W11 FROM [CP_Demand_G&PS]) AS FLOAT)/CAST(Rate_Hr AS FLOAT),2)),
        CP_ValueStream_Data.W12 = (SELECT ROUND(CAST((SELECT [CP_Demand_G&PS].W12 FROM [CP_Demand_G&PS]) AS FLOAT)/CAST(Rate_Hr AS FLOAT),2)),
        CP_ValueStream_Data.W13 = (SELECT ROUND(CAST((SELECT [CP_Demand_G&PS].W13 FROM [CP_Demand_G&PS]) AS FLOAT)/CAST(Rate_Hr AS FLOAT),2)),
        Active = 1
        FROM
            [CP_Demand_G&PS]
            INNER JOIN CP_ValueStream_Data 
        ON [CP_Demand_G&PS].RowLabels = CP_ValueStream_Data.Material
```

But when I execute the query this return a error

Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: You shouldn't be using subqueries in your SET part when you're already joining the table. Just `= ROUND(CAST([CP_Demand_G&PS].W... AS FLOAT)/...)`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the subqueries:

```
UPDATE CP_ValueStream_Data
    SET CP_ValueStream_Data.W1 = ROUND(CAST(d.W1 AS FLOAT)/CAST(Rate AS FLOAT), 2),
        . . .
        Active = 1
        FROM [CP_Demand_G&PS] d INNER JOIN 
             CP_ValueStream_Data v
             ON d.RowLabels = v.Material;
```